# how to send List<model> by adding its parameter as object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, collections

i have model with object parameter.

If there is 3 different candidate it should display 3 candidates, But my output is repeating the last candidate detail 3 times. I am not getting first 2 candidate details.

```
public class CandidateFeedbackDisplay implements Serializable{  
    private Candidate candidate;
    private List<Integer> feedbackIds;
//setter and getters
}




public List<CandidateFeedbackDisplay> list(Integer cID, Integer jID, String accepted) throws Exception {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Candidate> candidateList = null;
        CandidateFeedbackDisplay feedbackDisplay = new CandidateFeedbackDisplay();
        List<CandidateFeedbackDisplay> feedbackDisplayList = new ArrayList();
//      List<CandidateFeedbackDisplay> feedbackDisplayListTest = null;
        try {   
          Query query = session.createQuery("from Candidate WHERE phoneNumber IN (select DISTINCT mobileNo from InviteCandidates WHERE c_id= :cID AND j_id= :jID AND status= :accepted)");               
          query.setInteger("cID", cID);       
          query.setInteger("jID", jID);
          query.setString("accepted", accepted);          
          candidateList = query.list();
          Iterator itr = candidateList.iterator();
          while(itr.hasNext()){
              Candidate candidate = (Candidate) itr.next();
              System.out.println("candidate.getCandidateID() : " + candidate.getCandidateID());
              List<CandidateFeedback> candidateFeedback = this.getFeedback(cID, jID, candidate.getCandidateID());
              Iterator itr1 = candidateFeedback.iterator();
              List<Integer> feedbackid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
              while(itr1.hasNext()){                  
                  CandidateFeedback Feedback =  (CandidateFeedback) itr1.next();
                  feedbackid.add(Feedback.getFeedbackID());               
              }
              feedbackDisplay.setFeedbackIds(feedbackid);
              feedbackDisplay.setCandidate(candidate);            
              feedbackDisplayList.add(feedbackDisplay);
//            feedbackDisplayListTest.add(feedbackDisplay); // null pointer access error
          }
          }catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              this.logger.error("Error while fetching List :" + e);
              return null;
          }
        return feedbackDisplayList;
    }
```

Comment: First you need to explain your code (put comment) and point out exact code where you have issue and also remove unnecessary code

Comment: thank you for your quick reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the same object to the list three times. You have to create a new object every time by moving this line:

```
CandidateFeedbackDisplay feedbackDisplay = new CandidateFeedbackDisplay();
```

into the while loop, otherwise you keep changing the properties of the objects you put earlier. In fact, you are changing the same object, and add it to the list three times.

```
public List<CandidateFeedbackDisplay> list(Integer cID, Integer jID, String accepted) throws Exception {
    ...
    // DELETE HERE
    // CandidateFeedbackDisplay feedbackDisplay = new CandidateFeedbackDisplay();
    List<CandidateFeedbackDisplay> feedbackDisplayList = new ArrayList();
    try {   
        ...
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            ...
            // INSERT HERE
            CandidateFeedbackDisplay feedbackDisplay = new CandidateFeedbackDisplay();
            feedbackDisplay.setFeedbackIds(feedbackid);
            feedbackDisplay.setCandidate(candidate);            
            feedbackDisplayList.add(feedbackDisplay);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
    return feedbackDisplayList;
}
```

---

**Additional note**: In order to prevent such a mistake next time, you could change your parameter object CandidateFeedbackDisplay from setters to a constructor based implementation:

```
public class CandidateFeedbackDisplay {
    private final Candidate candidate;
    private final List<Integer> feedbackIds;

    public CandidateFeedbackDisplay(Candidate candidate, List<Integer> feedbackIds) {
        this.candidate = candidate;
        this.feedbackIds = feedbackIds;
    }

    // no setters
    // add getters or make fields public, but keep final
}
```

This way, you really show that this object is just an immutable value holder. You cannot make the same mistake again, and the constructor might shorten the code a bit. The benefits and drawbacks depend on your specific case, of course.

Comment: Thank you. you saved my day.

Comment: @Priya sure, glad to hear. I have added a small note to the end that can help preventing such a mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Put `CandidateFeedbackDisplay feedbackDisplay = new CandidateFeedbackDisplay();` Inside while loop because you are trying to prepare List of `CandidateFeedbackDisplay`

Please find below code, hope it will help.

```
while(itr.hasNext()){
        CandidateFeedbackDisplay feedbackDisplay = new CandidateFeedbackDisplay();
        Candidate candidate = (Candidate) itr.next();
        System.out.println("candidate.getCandidateID() : " + candidate.getCandidateID());
        List<CandidateFeedback> candidateFeedback = this.getFeedback(cID, jID, candidate.getCandidateID());
        Iterator itr1 = candidateFeedback.iterator();
        List<Integer> feedbackid = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(itr1.hasNext()){
            CandidateFeedback Feedback =  (CandidateFeedback) itr1.next();
            feedbackid.add(Feedback.getFeedbackID());
        }
        feedbackDisplay.setFeedbackIds(feedbackid);
        feedbackDisplay.setCandidate(candidate);
        feedbackDisplayList.add(feedbackDisplay);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply